# Extend Bootstrap Tooltip to support [data-type]

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am currently using the following jQuery to call Bootstrap's `tooltip` with an option to specify a custom class (for the purposes of recoloring the tooltip) via a `data-type` attribute.

```
   $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').each(function(){
        var options = { 
            html: true 
        };

        if ($(this)[0].hasAttribute('data-type')) {
            options['template'] = 
                '<div class="tooltip ' + $(this).attr('data-type') + '" role="tooltip">' + 
                '   <div class="tooltip-arrow"></div>' + 
                '   <div class="tooltip-inner"></div>' + 
                '</div>';
        }

        $(this).tooltip(options);
    });
```

What I'd prefer to do is have a way to actually extend `tooltip` to support this without all the extra customization at the event level, perhaps even to where you could quantify the coloring as an option.  I know that Bootstrap 2.3.2 allowed for some pretty nifty tricks with extending and customizing Bootstrap's base framework, but I cannot seem to find any answers specific to 3.x or even 4.x.

For a live example, visit: http://codepen.io/rkieru/pen/OXkdjV

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After attempting to determine a way to extend Bootstraps Tooltip Javascript to support this feature, I stumbled upon another CSS-only solution that still relies on `data-*` to provide the necessary coloring.

Bootstrap generates the Tooltip directly after the element with `data-toggle="tooltip"` so we can make use of the `+` selector like so:

```
/* Apply .btn-primary Coloring */
[data-color*="primary"] + .tooltip .tooltip-inner { background-color: #337ab7; }
[data-color*="primary"] + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #337ab7; }
[data-color*="primary"] + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #337ab7; }
[data-color*="primary"] + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #337ab7; }
[data-color*="primary"] + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #337ab7; }

/* Apply .btn-info Coloring */
[data-color*="info"] + .tooltip .tooltip-inner { background-color: #31b0d5; }
[data-color*="info"] + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #31b0d5; }
[data-color*="info"] + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #31b0d5; }
[data-color*="info"] + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #31b0d5; }
[data-color*="info"] + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #31b0d5; }

/* Apply .btn-success Coloring */
[data-color*="success"] + .tooltip .tooltip-inner { background-color: #449d44; }
[data-color*="success"] + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #449d44; }
[data-color*="success"] + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #449d44; }
[data-color*="success"] + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #449d44; }
[data-color*="success"] + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #449d44; }

/* Apply .btn-warning Coloring */
[data-color*="warning"] + .tooltip .tooltip-inner { background-color: #ec971f; }
[data-color*="warning"] + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #ec971f; }
[data-color*="warning"] + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #ec971f; }
[data-color*="warning"] + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #ec971f; }
[data-color*="warning"] + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #ec971f; }

/* Apply .btn-danger Coloring */
[data-color*="danger"] + .tooltip .tooltip-inner { background-color: #d9534f; }
[data-color*="danger"] + .tooltip.top > .tooltip-arrow { border-top-color: #d9534f; }
[data-color*="danger"] + .tooltip.right > .tooltip-arrow { border-right-color: #d9534f; }
[data-color*="danger"] + .tooltip.bottom > .tooltip-arrow { border-bottom-color: #d9534f; }
[data-color*="danger"] + .tooltip.left > .tooltip-arrow { border-left-color: #d9534f; }
```

From here it becomes as simple as adding `data-color=*` to the respective trigger element, like so:

`<div data-toggle="tooltip" data-color="success" title="I will be green!">Test</div>`